# Username in comments looks like tag?

Tags: discussion, support

*This isn't related to anything about tagging users in comments.*

---

Basically I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860111/warning-a-long-semaphore-wait). And something strange popped up. As you can see in the screenshot below, **Kay Nelson's** name has a background that looks like a tag?

[image]

Is there any particular reason why this happens? Or is it because I have the question favourited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Kay Nelson is the original poster. The person who started the question.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I was completely blind and didn't see it in the other questions. Man I need a smack on the head. Will accept when limit is up.

Comment: OP, as we like to reference it.